# Rotate svg text around central text position using css

Tags: css, svg, rotation, overwrite

I want to apply a single css rotation transformation to a set of elements in an SVG, such that each element is rotated independently, without having to calculate the centre of each element in the css. For example, I have an SVG that looks like the picture on the left, and want to apply css to achieve the effect on the right

[image: initial SVG]
[image: Desired result]

I'm writing the svg myself, and am creating something like this

```
<svg baseProfile="full" height="200" version="1.1" width="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <text transform="translate(50 100)" text-anchor="middle">Text 1</text>
    <text transform="translate(100 100)" text-anchor="middle">Text 2</text>
</svg>
```

When I apply a css rotation, e.g. by inserting `<style>text {transform: rotate(10deg)}</style>`, it seems to overwrite the first transformation, and the rotated text is placed in the top left corner:

[image]

I can modify the svg to use `x="X" y="Y" instead of a transform attribute, but that results in the transformation being applied around a different centre instead:

```
<svg baseProfile="full" height="200" version="1.1" width="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <style>text {transform: rotate(10deg)}</style>
    <text x="50" y="100" text-anchor="middle">Text 1</text>
    <text x="100" y="100"  text-anchor="middle">Text 2</text>
</svg>
```

[image]

How can I structure the svg so that I can apply a rotation which works independently on each element without overwriting the initial transform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

-The text has x="0" y="0" and is rotated with CSS.

-You put the text in the `<defs>`.

-You use the text and the `<use>` element has the `x` and `y` values you need.

```css
text{transform:rotate(90deg)}
```

```html
<svg baseProfile="full" viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
  <text id="a" text-anchor="middle" >Text 1</text>
  <text id="b" text-anchor="middle" >Text 2</text>
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#a" x="50" y="50" />
  <use xlink:href="#b" x="100" y="50" />
</svg>
```

Yet another solution (inspired by the comment of Robert Longson) would wrapping the rotated text in a g element and translate the g

```css
text{transform:rotate(90deg)}
```

```html
<svg baseProfile="full" viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 
      <g transform="translate(50,50)"><text text-anchor="middle" >Text 1</text></g>
      <g transform="translate(100,50)"><text text-anchor="middle" >Text 2</text></g>

 </svg>
```